# checking login with php

Tags: php

I'm making API to simple forum ,, Now trying to check Login with php

on the control page : checkLogin.php

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!isset($_POST['username']) or (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
        die('type the username & the password');
}
require_once('usersAPI.php'); 

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
        tinyf_db_close();
        die('bad User Info');
}
$user = tinyf_users_get_by_name($_POST['username']);

if(!$user)
{
        die('Bad User');
}
//check connection if mysqli couldn't fetch 
$pass = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($tf_handle, strip_tags($_POST['password'])));
tinyf_db_close();
// if(strcmp('n','n')) will be 0 and if(0) doesn't work :D
if(strcmp($pass,$user->password !== 0)){
        die('Bad__User');
}


die('success');
?>
```

> The result ===> Bad__User

i expected the result will be success

i think the function strcmp isn't working

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: why are you doing an sql escape on the entered password? `$pass` isn't being used in a query, therefore the escaping is pointless, and could lead to a password mismatch

Comment: you mean you're doing `md5($tf_handle, strip....)`? That's total cargo-cult programming... `md5($_POST['password'])` should be all you need.

Comment: but to avoid sql injection i saw someone doing like that while checking and it works fine with him

Comment: The parenthesis seem misplaced for `strcmp()`. It looks like you're intended to check `if (strcmp($pass,$user->password) !== 0)`. With that adjustment, and if your values are indeed both strings of "1", `strcmp()` will return `int(0)` and the `if` statement will not be executed. However, suggestions on using other hash/verification techniques are well-advised.

Comment: if (strcmp($pass,$user->password)!== 0){
        echo('Yup').'</br>';
}
else{
        echo('no').'</br>';
} 
 the result is no ... i already tried !== before :(

Comment: That's correct. But now you've switched the order of your output messages. Remember that you're testing for a *negated* match (`!== 0`). "Yup" should say "Doesn't Match" and "No" should say "Does Match". Here's [a demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64c62612ccf0db3e560dc11fa5fa4158a20e3d67).

Comment: Thanks put it as answer if u don't mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for PHP's [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is as follows:

> **strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )**
>   Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

The parenthesis in your code are misplaced:

```php
strcmp($pass,$user->password !== 0)
```

Rather than comparing the two values, you are comparing `$pass` with a boolean value that indicates whether `$user->password !== 0`. Given the fact that each of your variables is set to a string of "1", this is equivalent to `strcmp("1",false)` which returns `int(1)`, causes your `if` statement to return `true`, and outputs `die('Bad__User')`.

In order to properly compare your two values, the syntax will be:

```php
if ( strcmp($pass,$user->password) !== 0 ) {
    die('Bad__User');
}
```

Here's a [demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64c62612ccf0db3e560dc11fa5fa4158a20e3d67).

This being said, I believe commenters above have advised you well to consider more secure password hashing/validation techniques.